# Why can't I pull to the repo and what's the reason for error?

Tags: git, github, pull

I have looked extensively for a possible solution for this and continue to rerun through my steps, but I cannot get past the error I receive when I try to pull the master branch from my Repo.

So I have been pulling my Repo from my Github account with the following code:

```
$ git pull datascience master
```

I keep receiving this error:

```
fatal: 'datascience' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have verified my configuration in Gitbash and have checked that my remote "Datascience" is set up.

Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you clone the repo?

Comment: What's the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: _"I have verified my configuration in Gitbash and have checked that my remote "Datascience" is set up. "_ - how did you verify this?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

1. Double check your remote is setup properly via `git remote -v` - double check the URL!
2. If the above was all in order, maybe try removing it via `git remote rm datascience`, then re-add it via `git remote add datascience [URL]`

Do you by any chance have a link to the repository that we might be able to see in order to assist you further?

Hope this helps.